# Strange new Blender Video editor Hard Cut change?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, edit-mode, video, shortcut

Whenever I <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> or Hard cut a clip, the second half of the clip appears greyed out/slightly transparent on the timeline and doesn't play at all in the viewport.

It didn't use to do this, it's forcing me to soft cut anything if I want to use the footage on the second half of the split.

Is there a setting that's causing it to auto-mute or pause the second half of the cut?

Comment: Its a bug and has been repaired but you'll probably have to grab a recent build instead of official release. https://developer.blender.org/rBf3018322c097fe9893f73e2f66c1cd87ed30660c

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in Blender 2.79b. If you're experiencing this issue, odds are you're on 2.79a and should update.